# extjs 4.2.1 GridPanel - Show/Hide link in template column

Tags: javascript, templates, extjs, gridpanel

I have a template column in my `gridpanel` containing a URL:

```
{
    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<a href="#" class="x-leave-request-edit">Edit</a>'
    )
}
```

When a user mouses over a particular row in the `gridpanel`, I want the link to be visible:

```
listeners: {
    'itemmouseenter': function(gridpanel, record, item) {
        var editLink = Ext.select(Ext.query('a.x-leave-request-edit', item, 'select', true));
        editLink.setVisible(true);
    },
    'itemmouseleave': function(gridpanel, record, item) {
        var editLink = Ext.select(Ext.query('a.x-leave-request-edit', item, 'select', true));
        editLink.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

This works fine.  The problem though is that by default, I want the links in the `tpl` to be invisible.

How can I achieve this?

I tried using similar code as above in `onRender()`, `afterRender()` and `finishRender()` but the `Ext.query()` always returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all that `query` ugliness, you can just use:

`item.down('.x-leave-request-edit')`.

To make it not visible the initially, just add `display: none;` in the inline style.

```
return '<a href="#" style="display: none;" class="x-leave-request-edit">Edit</a>';
```

Comment: For some reason, the item.down('.x-leave-request-edit') call did not work.  I tried item.down('a.x-leave-request-edit') as well. Web Inspector says: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'item.down('a.x-leave-request-edit')').  On the other hand, your solution to add display:none; did.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that should be `Ext.fly(item).down()`